# Maven3 - can I declare "some implementation of api xy" is needed

Tags: java, api, maven-3

I split up my projects into multi-module projects often and heavily.

How can I declare in the Maven 3 POM that "Some implementation of API xy has to be available in the package".

For example, if I split my services layer in a `services-api` and `services-impl` and declare in the API that the deployable has to have a dependency on an implementation of `services-api`, even if its not the `services-impl` module itself.

Is this possible?

Comment: Seems more of a something that OSGi tries to solve.

Comment: The problem with this requirement is that implementations tend to be "provided" in the context of a Maven build environment. Most APIs I know that split between an API and an implementation solve this requirement at runtime, so they manually check if an implementation is on the classpath and then log an error if there is none.

Comment: Many thanks to Rekin and Gimby. I was afraid that maven would not provide me any help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an implementation of an API, then **something** has to choose which impl. If you don't care which, you have then 2 choices:

1. Either you just choose an impl and declare it in the POM, using `<scope>runtime</scope>`, which excludes the impl at compile time, but it will be made available to the container.
2. Or you use or implement a [Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html)

To quote from the Oracle tutorial (emphasis added):

> A set of programming interfaces and classes that provide access to some specific application functionality or feature. The service can define the interfaces for the functionality and **a way to retrieve an implementation**.